# Regluar expression - Remove Numerical Entry

Tags: regex

I want remove entries such as 0:1.2 and 14:12.4 and 196:4.6 from a text file using regular expressions.  A sed, awk, perl or generic regex suggestion would be appreciated.

Comment: Have you tried anything to accomplish this by yourself or are you just looking for an fast answer? http://www.regular-expressions.info/tutorial.html

Comment: What have you already achieved, dude?

Answer (score 1):

Without more details, I'd suggest this regular expression: `\d+:\d+\.\d`

It will match groups consisting of some digits, then a colon, some more digits, then a full stop and a last digit. I this doesn't describe what you want to match, you need to give more input.